# How to switch to a ui-router state conditionally?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am writing a CRUD app with AngularJS + UI Router.

I want to be able to parse the current location in the browser URL and determine if a ui-router state should be applicable for the current url.

In these sample routes, is there some way to do the `if` and `unless` clauses?

(url in browser address bar is `http://example.com/notes/1/edit_me`)

```
$stateProvider.state("root", {
    url: "",
    unless: $location.matches(/\edit_me/)
})

$stateProvider.state("edit", {
    url: "/edit",
    if: $location.matches(/\edit_me/)
    // 
})
```

**UPDATE 1**
The reason I want to do the above:

Say I am at `http://example.com/notes`. The routes is

```
$stateProvider.state("root", {
    url: "",
})
```

However, with the same above ui.route state, when I am at url `http://example.com/notes/edit`, the `root` is now "/notes/edit" instead of  "/notes"

**UPDATE 2**
**@adam, more explanation of what I am trying to accomplish:**

I will try to explain: in your code, for your `home` state, the (ui.router's) `url` is `/` (aka hash syntax `#!/`)

However, the URL in browser address bar looks like `http://example.com/notes/` in one case and `http://example.com/notes/edit` in another case. (note that the URLs do not contain any `#!` portion since we have just navigated to the page)

Now the `home`'s `/` is going to match in both cases of above URL.
But since the second URL ends in `notes/edit`, I want that the `home` for this URL should be `#!/edit`, and not `#!/`.

Basically I am trying to mix server-side rendered pages (**`/notes` and `/notes/edit` are rendered by server, not AngularJS**)
and client side routing so that no matter which URL we are at, the client can figure out which (ui.router) route applies to the current URL.

Make sense?

Comment: Can i know exactely in you case, why do you want to check url? Do you want to set an active css class for example ?

Comment: Thanks @adam, I updated the question with the reason

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i don't really understand your needs but here's an example of use of ui-router:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'app/main/index.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
$stateProvider
  .state('edit', {
    url: '/edit',
    templateUrl: 'app/edit/edit.html',
    controller: 'EditCtrl'
  })
$stateProvider
  .state('edit.note', {
    url: '/note',
    templateUrl: 'app/edit/note.html',
    controller: 'NoteCtrl'
  });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

i'm not sure if a copy paste will work, but try to adapt it with your case. Hope it will help.

**Edit:**

I'm afraid that i can't help you more than that. The design of your app with rendered page without angular sounds really special.
Have you tried the example i provide you? If yes, hav you simply format the url by addind

" **#!/** " where you need it.

For example:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('edit', {
    url: '#!/edit', //or something like, url:'/#!/edit'
    templateUrl: 'app/edit/edit.html',
    controller: 'EditCtrl'
});
```

Check this link also may be it will help you:https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/372

**ui-sref** may help you
But the place to see usefull example for ui-router it's his own doc.
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

and here:
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router